# Custom url scheme not working (for first time) IOS application

Tags: ios, custom-url, distributed-apps

I have created one distribution application also register custom URL scheme. First time after I installed application, and try custom URL link, it does not work.

However if I lunch the application manually it will prompt me below mentioned message

```
Are you sure you want to open the application ... from the developer iphone distribution ... ?
```

I will click on continue, and after that custom URL link works fine with my application.

Can Custom url link launch the application directly on installation (without manually launch application and contiue)?

Also is there any settings, so we can make the prompt message off. So it will not prompt message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Custom url link launch the application directly on installation
>   (without manually launch application and contiue)?

No. Just make sure that the user is aware of which application they are installing. Then they can manually open it up for the first time; your URL scheme will work fine after that.

> Also is there any settings, so we can make the prompt message off. So
>   it will not prompt message.

No there is not. This message is generated by the operating system and cannot be turned off. It is a security feature for enterprise-level applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But We had tried to create new application from another enterprise account then it do not prompt that message . –

Comment: Strange behaviour, as i create build of same application with two different enterprise account profile. 

for one profile, when first time i launch application it prompts message, but for another profile it does not prompt message. 

i want the behaviour like message should not be prompt. and custom url can work immediatly after installation. 

can anybody please help me, is there any configuration settings, certificate/provisioning profile settings?

Comment: You mentioned that this worked in a new application; can you check the configuration settings to see if there is anything that is different?

Comment: James as i comment above, now even in same application with diff. enterprise account one is working fine (not prompt message and custom url works), for other it will prompt message

Comment: i tried to install an application with both enterprise account on new ios device, and for both message will be prompt, seems other devices has other applications with same enterprise account,so it did not prompt message.